# How to append data to the body of a request in Next js using Middleware?

Tags: session, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I am creating a NextJs project using Supabase. In Supabase, there is a users table that contains authenticated users. Each user is assigned a uuid (user_id). In the project, the users can fill a form and register themselves as employees and get added in the employees table of the db. The primary key of the employees table is the uuid of the users table i.e. when a user registers themselves as an employee, the id of the employee should be taken from the user_id in the users table.

Now, when users fill the form and submit, the API request is made to insert the user. The user_id is not sent in the body of the request. So, I need a way to send the user_id in the body of the API along with the other user info (like name etc.)

The way I want to do this is by using middleware. In the middleware, I want to get the user session, get the `user_id` from there and then add that `user_id` to the body of the request that will go to the API.

This is my middleware.ts:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse, Body } from 'next/server';

import { createSupabaseReqResClient } from '@/lib/supabase/server-clients';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let modifiedRequest = request;

  const supabase = createSupabaseReqResClient(request, NextResponse.next());

  const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

  const user = session?.user;

  if (!user && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/my-profile')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }

  // Check if the request is being made to the /api/employee endpoint
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/api/employee') {
    const body = await request.json();
    const user_id = user?.id;
    // Create a new Body object with the modified body
    const modifiedBody = new Body(JSON.stringify({ ...body, id: user_id }));
    // Create a new NextRequest object with the modified body
    modifiedRequest = {
      ...request,
      body: modifiedBody,
    };
  }

  return NextResponse.next(modifiedRequest);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/my-profile','/api/employee'],
};
```

This is throwing me error in the following part of the code:

```
    modifiedRequest = {
      ...request,
      body: modifiedBody,
    };
```

The error:

```
Type '{ body: any; [INTERNALS]: { cookies: RequestCookies;
 geo: { city?: string | undefined;
 country?: string | undefined;
 region?: string | undefined; latitude?: string | undefined;
 longitude?: string | undefined; } | undefined;
 ip?: string | undefined;
 url: string; nextUrl: NextURL; };
 ... 18 more ...;
 text(): Promise<....' is missing the following properties 
from type 'NextRequest': cookies, geo, ip, nextUrl, and 3 more.ts(2740)
let modifiedRequest: NextRequest
```

What is wrong with my middleware? And is there some other approach I can take to access/send `user_id` in the API to insert it in database?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to handle this in the middleware and not in your API route (/api/employee)?

Comment: Not really, this is just one approach I could think of. Initially, I was trying to get the user session in the api/employee by using the supabaseClient, 
 ```const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabaseClient.auth.getSession();
  console.log('session that is present in the route', session);
```

but the session I am getting is NULL

Comment: Okay, I got the user and user_id in my api by using server supabase client.

Comment: Great! you should be able to reference an employee (from the employees table), using the `user_id`, and IMO this is much cleaner than doing it in the middleware.